# How to add multiple <td> in a row javascript

Tags: javascript, object, innerhtml

```
const list = document.querySelector('#book');
const row = document.createElement('tr');

>     row.innerHTML ='
>     <td>${book.title}</td>
>     <td>${book.author}</td>
>     <td>${book.number}</td>
>     <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-smdelete">X</a></td>
>                     ';

list.appendChild(row);
```

The problem is why cant I use that method to add multiple **td** in **tr** I get error, how to fix it? I know the other method using `insertRow() then create insertCell()` but I don't want to use it.

Comment: `I get error` - what error? .... try using `\`` instead of `'`

Comment: or add backslash at the end of each line but ${} doesn't work

Comment: it's fixed, thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var books = [{
  title: "IT",
  author: "Stephen King",
  number: "0987654321"
}, {
  title: "Pet Sematary",
  author: "Stephen King",
  number: "1234567890"
}]

const list = document.querySelector('#book');

books.forEach(function(book) {
  const row = document.createElement('tr');
  const tdBook = document.createElement('td');
  const tdAuthor = document.createElement('td');
  const tdNumber = document.createElement('td');
  const tdLink = document.createElement('a');

  tdBook.innerText = book.title;
  tdAuthor.innerText = book.author;
  tdNumber.innerText = book.number;
  tdLink.href = "#";
  tdLink.classname = "btn btn-danger btn-smdelete";
  tdLink.innerText = "X";

  row.appendChild(tdBook);
  row.appendChild(tdAuthor);
  row.appendChild(tdNumber);
  row.appendChild(tdLink);

  list.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<table id="book">

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the new knowledge but I got fixed the problems, I didn't know the difference using ``` and `'` thanks to @Jaromanda X and everyone involved now I know :)